# probability two color gloves wearing on same hand

Tags: probability

u have two colored gloves you wear 12 times in a row and pick each one at random out of a hat . what is the probability to nearest hundredth that you will wear one color on the same hand exactly six times ? alternatively: After wearing a pair of gloves a dozen times, what is the probability to the nearest hundrtedth
that each glove has been on each hand  exactly a half dozen times? doing the possabilities  by hand say Red and Blue we would get as a half dozen times sequence : RBRBBRBRBRRBRBBRRBRBBR.. I then thought it would be 12C6 / 2^12

Comment: This is not clear.  Are we to imagine that you only wear one glove at a time?  And for the second part...gloves can only be worn on one hand, so what are you asking?

Comment: one glove at a time ..reworded -what are the chances that after putting on the gloves every day for 12 days ..taking them off at night .. that in those 12 days that each glove worn on each hand only 6 times ?

Comment: The gloves are very confusing.  Is your question really just "say you toss a fair coin $12$ times.  What is the probability of getting exactly $6$ Heads?"  If so, your answer is right.

Comment: i dont know , is it ?

Comment: I don't understand the glove version, so I have no idea.  I'm just guessing here.

Comment: if it is then i was right its 12c6 over 2^12 ..about .23

Comment: it was on an AMATYC contest 1999 november

Comment: Please print the question exactly as it appeared with no edits.

Comment: its already solved 

Answer (score 0):

number 20 of this test . and usually the last problem of these tests is more on the side of difficult then the ones 1-15 .but this one wasn't so tough .[image]

Comment: Can you see where there is a huge difference between socks and gloves?  Each glove can only go on one hand...this is not true for socks.  Still, it come down to a coin toss on each day, so your original answer is correct.

Comment: what socks can go on two feet ??

Comment: one sock can go on two feet ? theres no difference just that i prefer gloves as i wear a glove at least once a week with the many females 